# Is there any way to skip the crop screen in the Sincerely Ship library?

Tags: ios, image-processing

My application handles photo editing already, which includes cropping. Is there anyway to skip this screen in the [Sincerely Ship library](http://dev.sincerely.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing! Just pass the sincerely library an image which is already resized to the correct print size when calling the `initWithImages: product: applicationKey: delegate:`. Print images should be either 1800x1200 or 1200x1800 pixels.